# Django error on localhost, not reconizing f"Lote: {self.title}"

Tags: python, django

I got this error running python manage.py of my Django Application:

> File "/home/lucas/Documents/back/user/models.py", line 6, in
>   
>       from coupon.models import Coupon   File "/home/lucas/Documents/back/coupon/models.py", line 26
>       return f"Lote: {self.title}"
>                                  ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The same code works fine on the server machine. Is there something missing to run it local?

I installed all dependencies and requirements and try to search for what may cause this error, without success.

Packages installed:

**python -version**:
Python 3.5.2

**python-dev** installed

**pip** installed

**build-essential** installed

**python3** installed

**System**:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

Also all python libs installed

Looking for any help to solve this.

Comment: The problem is your python version. These formatted strings are works with python 3.6 or higher

Comment: Please show your `models.py`

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi no need, `f"Lote: {self.title}"` doesn't work in python 3.5

Comment: so either change to `"Lote: {title}".format(title=self.title)` or upgrade to python 3.6